# encoder output features different from same wav file

Tags: pytorch, wav, encoder

I am passing a audio file through the [`Wav2Vec2FeatureEncoder`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/04ab5605fbb4ef207b10bf2772d88c53fc242e83/src/transformers/models/wav2vec2/modeling_wav2vec2.py#L405). It passes through the 7 convolutional layer, the params being

`conv_dim=(512,512,512,512,512,512,512)`

`feat_extract_norm="layer"`.

The output is different every time, although it should output the same features. What could be the reason? Do I need to save the convolution filter parameters somewhere and load it, how to do that?

```
import soundfile as sf

x, _ = sf.read(wav)                                                      # float64 of shape (36864,)
x_aug = torch.tensor(audio_augment(x), dtype=torch.float, device=device) # x_aug is a tensor of shape torch.Size([16, 1, 36864]) where batch_size = 16

encoder = Wav2Vec2FeatureEncoder()
encoder_feat = encoder(x)
```

> Wav2Vec2FeatureEncoder

```
 class Wav2Vec2FeatureEncoder(nn.Module):
    """Construct the features from raw audio waveform"""

    def __init__(
            self,
            conv_dim=(512,512,512,512,512,512,512),
            feat_extract_norm="layer"
    ):
        super().__init__()

        self.num_feat_extract_layers = len(conv_dim)
        """
        if config.feat_extract_norm == "group":
            conv_layers = [Wav2Vec2GroupNormConvLayer(config, layer_id=0)] + [
                Wav2Vec2NoLayerNormConvLayer(config, layer_id=i + 1) for i in range(config.num_feat_extract_layers - 1)
            ]
        """
        if feat_extract_norm == "layer":
            conv_layers = [
                Wav2Vec2LayerNormConvLayer(layer_id=i) for i in range(self.num_feat_extract_layers)
            ]
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                f"`config.feat_extract_norm` is {feat_extract_norm}, but has to be one of ['group', 'layer']"
            )
        self.conv_layers = nn.ModuleList(conv_layers)
        self.gradient_checkpointing = False
        self._requires_grad = True

    def _freeze_parameters(self):
        for param in self.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
        self._requires_grad = False

    def forward(self, input_values):
        hidden_states = input_values
        
        # make sure hidden_states require grad for gradient_checkpointing
        if self._requires_grad and self.training:
            hidden_states.requires_grad = True

        for conv_layer in self.conv_layers:
            if self._requires_grad and self.gradient_checkpointing and self.training:

                def create_custom_forward(module):
                    def custom_forward(*inputs):
                        return module(*inputs)

                    return custom_forward

                hidden_states = torch.utils.checkpoint.checkpoint(
                    create_custom_forward(conv_layer),
                    hidden_states,
                )
            else:
                hidden_states = conv_layer(hidden_states)
                print(hidden_states[0][0][0].item())

        return hidden_states
```

> Wav2Vec2LayerNormConvLayer

```
class Wav2Vec2LayerNormConvLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            layer_id=0,
            conv_dim=(512,512,512,512,512,512,512),
            conv_kernel=(10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2),
            conv_stride=(5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
            conv_bias=False,
            feat_extract_activation="gelu"
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_conv_dim = conv_dim[layer_id - 1] if layer_id > 0 else 1
        self.out_conv_dim = conv_dim[layer_id]

        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(
            self.in_conv_dim,
            self.out_conv_dim,
            kernel_size=conv_kernel[layer_id],
            stride=conv_stride[layer_id],
            bias=conv_bias,
        )
        self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(self.out_conv_dim, elementwise_affine=True)
        self.activation = ACT2FN[feat_extract_activation]

    def forward(self, hidden_states):
        hidden_states = self.conv(hidden_states)

        hidden_states = hidden_states.transpose(-2, -1)
        hidden_states = self.layer_norm(hidden_states)
        hidden_states = hidden_states.transpose(-2, -1)

        hidden_states = self.activation(hidden_states)
        return hidden_states
```

Comment: call encoder.eval() before passing your inputs

Answer (score 0):

The bug was stupid, I was initializing the `Wav2Vec2FeatureEncoder` for each input, when it should have been initialized only once. I was doing the following

```
# x1=x2=same wav file
encoder = Wav2Vec2FeatureEncoder()
encoder_feat = encoder(x1)

encoder2 = Wav2Vec2FeatureEncoder()
encoder2_feat = encoder2(x2)
```

when it should have been:

```
encoder = Wav2Vec2FeatureEncoder()
x1_feat = encoder(x1)
x2_feat = encoder(x2)
```